# How is this output coming?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
 char str_a[20]; 
 char *pointer; 
 char *pointer2; 
 strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
 pointer = str_a; 
 printf(pointer);
 pointer2 = pointer + 2;
 printf(pointer2); 
 strcpy(pointer2, "y you guys!\n"); 
 printf(pointer); 
}
```

Hi..can you tell me how the output comes like:=

```
Hello, world! 
llo, world! 
Hey you guys!
```

Actually I am new to the pointers in C.So finding it bit difficult to grasp. Any help regarding pointers would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So what results have you come to so far? This is quite trivial.

Answer (score 4):

The first one:

```
pointer = str_a; 
printf(pointer);
```

`pointer` points to "Hello, wold!\n" (str_a), so that what is getting printed.

The second:

```
pointer2 = pointer + 2;
printf(pointer2);
```

`pointer2` points to 2 chars after `pointer`, which is the third character of "Hello, wold!\n", so `llo world` is printed

The third:

```
strcpy(pointer2, "y you guys!\n"); 
printf(pointer);
```

now, you copy 'y you guys' to the address in `pointer2`, which is still two char into `pointer`, so the first two chars of the string are still the same.

```
memory: H  e  l  l  o  ,     w  o  r  l  d  \  n
        ^     ^
pointer-+     |
pointer2------+
```

`strcpy(pointer2, "y you guys!\n");` overrides from `pointer2`, e.g. the first 'l'

Comment: +1, with a nit: `pointer2` points to *2 elements of `char` type* after `pointer`, not 2 bytes; remember that pointer arithmetic is done relative to the size of the base type, not in raw bytes.

Comment: Thanks. I will make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

The first `strcpy`copies the quoted string constant into the `str_a` buffer. You then print the buffer via a pointer to its start. `pointer2` is set to point two characters further into the buffer than `pointer` (both are of type pointer-to-char) and then the contents of the buffer from the third character on are printed.

The second `strcpy` copies the quoted string into the buffer starting at the third character and overwriting the previous contents. Note that the first two characters were not overwritten, so when the full contents of the buffer are written out, they show up.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are numbers (usually 4 bytes on 32bit systems, 8 bytes on 64bit systems) which represent an address in logical memory. For example, if you have 4GiB of memory available, your pointers will contain values from 0 to 4294967295. You can have pointers to different types of things in C. The type of the pointer does not affect the address it stores, but it does affect how it will be incremented. `int *a; a += 1;` will increment `a` by 4 bytes, or possibly 8, depending on the size of an `int` on your system.

1. `strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");` copies the buffer containing `"Hello, world!\n"` into `str_a`, which is a pointer to 20 `char`s. Arrays in C are just pointers that have some memory preallocated starting with the address of the array.
2. `pointer = str_a;` makes the `pointer` point to the same address as `str_a`.
3. `pointer2 = pointer + 2;` makes `pointer2` point two characters down in the same string as `pointer`.
4. `strcpy(pointer2, "y you guys!\n");` replaces all but the first two characters of the original string stored in `str_a` and `pointer` with the new text, because that is where `pointer2` is pointing now.

Comment: No, pointers are not integers.

Comment: @H2CO3. True, they are not ints, but they are integer quantities. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is bad practice to print string using `printf` without using `%s` specifier.
Now on the question;

The statement

```
 strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
```

will copy the string `"Hello, world!"` to `str_a`.

```
 pointer = str_a;
```

will assign that string to `pointer`. `pointer` is pointing to the first `char` of the string ,i.e, `H`.

```
 printf(pointer);
```

will print the string `"Hello, world!"`.

```
  pointer2 = pointer + 2;
```

will add 2 units to the `pointer` and now the `pointer2` will points to the third `char` of the string `"Hello, world!"` , i.e, `l` (fist). Now `pointer` and `pointer2` points to the same string `"Hello, world!"` but have different starting addresses. Now

```
 strcpy(pointer2, "y you guys!\n");
```

will copy `"y you guys!\n"` to the `pointer2` and the string `"llo, world!"` will become `"y you guys!"`. Since any changes done by a pointer to a pointee is reflected to all of its pointers points to hence, now the original string `"Hello, world!"` will become now `"Hey you guys!"` and the statement

```
printf(pointer);
```

will print  `Hey you guys!`.